# TypeScript - iterate over types in a dictionary type and create a type with transformed values

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Note: This is not about runtime, we are talking purely about types here.

Suppose there are types: `Alpha<T>`, `Beta<T>` and an example type like `type Data = {a: Alpha<number>; b: Beta<string>, c: Alpha<string> }` I need to transform it to something like: `{a: number; b: string; c: string }`

I know how to transform a single value, I have this implemented already, but I have no idea how could I iterate over a dictionary type with known properties and transform them. Is it even possible?

```
class Alpha<T> {
    private a: T;
}

class Beta<T> {
    private b: T;
}

// Extracts T from Alpha<T> or Beta<T> - already implemented
type GetClassParameterForAlphaBeta<T extends Alpha<any> | Beta<any>> =
    T extends Alpha<infer R>
    ? R : T extends Beta<infer R>
    ? R : unknown;

type Store = { [index: string]: Alpha<any> | Beta<any> }

// pseudo-code to give you an idea of what I'm after
type GetStoreData<T extends Store> = T each U : GetClassParameterForAlphaBeta<U>;

type Data = {a: Alpha<number>; b: Beta<string>, c: Alpha<string> }

type x = GetStoreData<Data> // Expected: {a: number; b: string, c: string }
```

One thing to note is that the 2 classes are known, but `Data` in the real case is a generic. It has a finite amount of properties, but it's all dynamic. Manually applying the transformations is out of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, you're just looking for a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type GetStoreData<T extends Store> = {
  [K in keyof T]: GetClassParameterForAlphaBeta<T[K]>
}
```

You can verify that it works as expected:

```
type X = GetStoreData<Data> 
/* type X = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCIAcAWYA8AVAfNA3gWAChpoEAnASwDcwAXAU2jAC5p0BuQgX0MNEhgBCdGmiy5CxMlVoMARi3ZceBAPQroAUQAeNUmGA0Y6aADNSAewC2cRCgzZzpaEJH3oAWkYhSdMABMAT2hySwQQOks6ADt6P0IaAIQGAHFhAGFwKAAFMD1I+lIAMUd4ZDAXUWg6HWi-GFK7MCiA7AAfZ2E0JpbsAF4JViqaqLqbMtRyKJM6JwAlTAGAfmhZ6AUh+hHBTompmZWFomhl1ZYAVyiAayjzAHcojgJ4xIYAZRpHBl7caABtSb81RYEF0kwA5gBdFgNLrNNodVzdbDcJ6qdQICB0M5+czuYDmQHQD7QMFUBgBcxnRhRYKAsDQcwmaC3FA0aAASQA5NYwCYCs8ktBUjR3p8ACK0SrVTajUU+PriI6-ADSwRplzoFKZ6ChQvSmQgOTywhmxVIMIqGBVEMOKIFDAlImg3xwjGhtjQUTOllkM0wbGg8gRaBBFCiYMwABpoMB3eNQ+DkcoEoKABrOvUij4+R1oXPYQgqABURJe0HTLoGxGY0C9Ppmj2IxCDCfDjabsegrbBj040CLKiAA)