# Converting types from object of arrays to array of objects typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have an API whose response is as follows:

```
{
  age: [1,2,3],
  name: ['Alan', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
  fruit: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry']
}
```

The ideal response for a table format should have had been (and I've written a function that does this.

```
[
  {age: 1, name: 'Alan', fruit: 'Apple'},
  {age: 2, name: 'Bob', fruit: 'Banana'},
  {age: 3, name: 'Charlie', fruit: 'Cherry'},
]
```

The type definition for the table is as follows:

```
interface TableRowProps {
  age: number
  name: string
  fruit: string
}

type TableDataProps = Array<TableRowProps>
```

I'm trying to find a way to convert the type definition from interface for the table to one for the API response, so the eventual result will be

```
interface ApiResponseProps {
  age: Array<number>
  name: Array<string>
  fruit: Array<string>
}
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
type ApiResponseProps<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: Array<Property>
}

const myvar: NewProps<TableRowProps> = [...array-based data]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I am looking for mapped types, and I was pretty close. The correct for `ApiResponseProps` would have had been:

```
type ApiResponseProps<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: Array<Type[Property]>
}
```

I spent about 2-3 hours fiddling with `infer`. I don't have any examples of that left (rage-deleted a lot of code), but would appreciate it if someone could explain why infer would have had been a bad choice. Many thanks :)

[Sample TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=37#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwJYBE5TjAvDA3gKBngHMBTALhgG0BGAGgCY6BmAXTsJjDgFsLqA5AEEANnDAC6MAQCEQAI0nSAwgAs4AJxFJSA9pwBmGgK5IolKsIQIRuqbPGOlAtaQ0aAnnvwBffPiQwKDcDOGBSGAAVOHlbACUQAHcABQ0QBAg8TjgySjBjHnk3Tm4+SmgNQOJDEzNyqEqwar98UEhYDFjSNAxKIXc4DwAeaK6ElLSMgD5sak5cHP56Ll5+YTEJKSNTc2kha1sBHw4iBdyYJhWy6TlFLdrdh25uI5O8RcpmKVK1tU1tOwwbZ1FSqNyeV74Vj+KAeBARfZIOKkCAIcAQUipdIQEZw0gzHAEIhULHwjSwmCBGAAa1IHhABiieNYfQGw0ieJJkzcsNYU18-ja0BgxgQABN0KQxYjkaj0fwZSi0ZBMZMcaN4klSRACVkiB9qPQmGw3j8LOtxM5bs4-lodHo3sDdpZ9jZAU8nPZXO4vNC-EA)

Comment: Got a lot of help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128641/3687878)